# Showing sets are open in $\Bbb R^2$ with an unusual topology

Tags: general-topology

On $\Bbb R^2$, let $X$ be the set of lines:
$$
X=\left \{ \lambda \left ( \cos \frac{k \pi}{36}, \sin \frac{k \pi}{36} \right ): \lambda \in \Bbb R,\;  k \in \Bbb N \right \}.
$$
We call the origin $O$ and we define the rays metric on $X$ as
$$
d(M,N)= \left\{\begin{matrix}
 d_{\Bbb{R}^2}(M,N) \qquad \text{if} \; \;\exists \; \lambda \in \Bbb{R} : M=\lambda N & \\ 
 d_{\Bbb{R}^2}(M,O)+d_{\Bbb{R}^2}(O,N) \qquad \qquad \text{else} & 
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
We consider the following sets:
$A=\left \{ (x,0): 1<x<3 \right \}$ and $B=\left \{ (x,0): -1<x<4 \right \}$.

My question are, why is $A$ open with respect to the topology induced by the rays metric, and why is $B$ not open with respect to the same topology?

Answer (score 2):

Let us take any $(a,0)\in A$. Let $r=\min\{|a-1|,|3-a|\}$. Then $B_d((a,0),r)\subseteq A$. Hence $A$ is open.

Let us call $X_{k}$, the ray corresponding to the angle $\frac{k\pi}{36}$. Note that in ray metric

> For any $\delta>0$ and $k\in\Bbb{N}$ $$B_d((0,0),\delta)\cap X_k=\{\lambda(\cos(k\pi/36),\sin(k\pi/36))\mid\lambda\in(-\delta,\delta)\}$$.

Note that $A,B\subseteq X_{0}$. However $B$ contains the point $(0,0)$, and it cannot contain any open ball centered at $(0,0)$, because $B_d((0,0),\delta)\cap X_k\not\subseteq B$ for $k\not\in 36\Bbb{Z}$. Hence $B$ cannot be open. And $B$ does not contain $(-1,0)$ or $(4,0)$, so it is not closed either.

Comment: In short, the origin is not an inner point of $B$.

Comment: Yeah...that is why it is not open

Comment: The topology on $X$ induced by $d$ is not unusual; it is the subspace topology from the usual topology on $\Bbb R^2$..........+1

Answer (score 0):

B is NOT closed as $(-1,0)$ and $(4,0)$ are in $\bar B.$

For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $L(n)=\{r(\cos n\pi/36,\,\sin n\pi/36):r\in \Bbb R\}.$

Observe there exists $s>0$ such that if $x>1$ and $0\ne n\in \Bbb N$ then $d_{\Bbb R^2}(\,(x,0), M\,)>s$ for any $M\in L(n).$

So for $1<x<3$ let $t_x=\min (s,|x-1|,|x-3|,1).$ Then in $X$ we have $$A=\cup \{B_d(\,(x,0),t_x\,): 1<x<3\}.$$

Remark: The metric $d$ applied to all of $\Bbb R^2$ is called the Hedgehog Metric.